# use of @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional outside of the DAO layer?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

i have a quite classical issus : Access Lazy Collection outside of the DAO, witch lead to LazyInitializationException.

Is that a clean and reasonable solution to use `@Transactional` one some method of the service, outside of the DAO, who use these lazy collection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. The one who knows which tasks must be a unit of work (a Transaction) is the service, because it is the one who "knows" the business.

Comment: +1. Transactional DAOs instead of services are a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

[Neuquino has the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459661/use-of-org-springframework-transaction-annotation-transactional-outside-of-the-d/4459711#4459711), but it's not very clear and understandable, so I'll try to rephrase it:

You usually want one transaction for one service method, which is why you annotate the service layer with `@Transactional`, not the DAO layer. (The nice thing about the Spring `@Transactional` annotation is that it is independent of the underlying implementation, so there should usually be no code in the service layer that's specific to your persistence layer, e.g. no calls to hibernate `Session` or JPA `EntityManager` ). When unit testing DAOs, put the `@Transactional` annotations on the test methods (your tests are services, not DAOs).